# Script Not executing.... returning errors

Tags: bash, shell

I am beginner in bash. The script has to execute to find the requested file and check for the permissions. and search for the string "to" in the particular file

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -e "$1"]
then
echo "The file does not exist!"
exit 1
elif [ ! -r "$1"]
then
echo "You do not have read permission on this file!"
exit2
fi
count=0
while read line do
    for word in $line do
        if [ $word = "to" ]
            then
            count='expr$count+1'
        fi
    done
done<$1
echo "The word 'to' occurred $count times in your file"
```

Comment: Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

Always test your script when you have syntax errors on https://www.shellcheck.net/

It can explain you that you miss a space in all `if` conditions:

```
if [ ! -e "$1"]
```

VS

```
if [ ! -e "$1" ]
#             ^
#          mandatory
```

There's another small issues I let you discover yourself on shellcheck.

And the arithmetic is plain wrong. Please, consider:

```
while IFS= read -r line do
    for word in $line; do
        if [[ $word == to ]]; then
            ((++count))
        fi
    done
done < "$1"
echo "The word 'to' occurred $count times in your file"
```

[how to read a file line by line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

---

`((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

---

`[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals. Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, we recommend `[[`.

---

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: "$var", "$(command "$var")", "${array[@]}", "a & b". Use 'single quotes' for code or literal $'s: 'Costs $5 US', ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes , http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: Thanks for your help.It really helped a lot